# sstableloader does not transmit the data, and refer to the weirf ports

Tags: cassandra, bulkloader

I want to bulkload my cassandra data from node A to node B.

when I set the '**listen_address**' of each **cassandra.yaml** file to localhost,
they do not show error on console but the data is never transmitted.

when I set each node's **listen address** to their own local network[eth1 ipv4]address (192.168....), I get the following error.

I can read from this error log that **the application is trying to access to port 1..4**
and I do not have no idea what on earth is going on.

each node is on the virtual machine on the Virtual Box Hypervisor. Both OS is centOS.

```
[vagrant@localhost conf]$ ../bin/sstableloader   -v -d 192.168.33.12  -p 9160 /db/data/m
oomin/hoahoa2/                                                                          
Streaming revelant part of /db/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-hf-69-Data.db to [/192.168.33.12]

progress: [/192.168.33.12 0/1 (0)] [total: 0 - 0MB/s (avg: 0MB/s)] WARN 16:55:42,655 Failed attempt 1 to connect to /192.168.33.12 to stream /db/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-h
f-69-Data.db sections=1 progress=0/378000000 - 0%. Retrying in 4000 ms. (java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address)
progress: [/192.168.33.12 0/1 (0)] [total: 0 - 0MB/s (avg: 0MB/s)] WARN 16:55:46,658 Failed attempt 2 to connect to /192.168.33.12 to stream /db/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-h
f-69-Data.db sections=1 progress=0/378000000 - 0%. Retrying in 8000 ms. (java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address)
progress: [/192.168.33.12 0/1 (0)] [total: 0 - 0MB/s (avg: 0MB/s)] WARN 16:55:54,666 Failed attempt 3 to connect to /192.168.33.12 to stream /db/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-h
f-69-Data.db sections=1 progress=0/378000000 - 0%. Retrying in 16000 ms. (java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address)
progress: [/192.168.33.12 0/1 (0)] [total: 0 - 0MB/s (avg: 0MB/s)]
```

Here is my cassandra.yaml (the cassandra.yaml of target file is also configured the same way)

```
# communicate!
#
# Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
# will always do the Right Thing *if* the node is properly configured
# (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
# address associated with the hostname (it might not be).
#
# Setting this to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong.
listen_address: 192.168.33.12
#listen_address: localhost  
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
# port for Thrift to listen for clients on
rpc_port: 9160

# enable or disable keepalive on rpc connections
rpc_keepalive: true

rpc_server_type: sync

thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
```

thrift_max_message_length_in_mb: 16

```
incremental_backups: false

snapshot_before_compaction: false

auto_snapshot: true

column_index_size_in_kb: 64

in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64

multithreaded_compaction: false

compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16

compaction_preheat_key_cache: true

rpc_timeout_in_ms: 10000

endpoint_snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.PropertyFileSnitch

dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1

request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler


emory usage without a impact on performance.
index_interval: 128
```

Can anybody give me advice? I am really suffering as hell.